# How does one pass on parameters in assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, hook

im working on a hook in C++ and ASM and currently i have just made an easy inline hook that places a jump in the first instruction of the target function which in this case is OutputDebugString just for testing purposes.

the thing is that my hook fianlly works after about 3 days of research and figuring out the bits and peaces of how things work, but there is one problem i have no idea how to change the parameters that come in to my "dummy" function before jumping on to the rest of the original function.

as u can see in my code i have tried to change the parameter simply in C++ but of course this does not work as im poping all the registers afterwards :/

anyways here is my dummy function which is what the hooked function jumps to:

```
static void __declspec(naked) MyDebugString(LPCTSTR lpOutputString) {
     __asm {
         PUSHAD
     }

     //Where i suppose i could run my code, but not be able to interfere with parameters :/
     lpOutputString = L"new message!";

     __asm {
         POPAD
         MOV EDI, EDI
         PUSH EBP
         MOV EBP, ESP
         JMP Addr
     }

     original_DebugString(lpOutputString);
}
```

i understand why the code is not working as i said, i just can't see a proper solution to this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to MOV your parameter to working register, do an ADD with something that will make the necessary change, and then MOV again to the location you will use for argument to the function.

Comment: In pure assembly language, you *usually* pass parameters in registers. When mixing assembly with C (or whatever) you deal with parameters passed as that language sees fit to pass them. In this case, it would probably be on the stack (just below the return address). That said, your code doesn't seem to make any real sense.

Comment: I suggest you to just make a c/c++ function with some parameters and local variables and for example `__stdcall` convention and look in a disassembler at how the compiler generated asm code interacts with parameters and local stack variables and learn from it. It uses a simple trick to not always have to count how many `push*/pop*`s there have been.

Comment: Also, if you don't really want to deal with the asm hell every beginner experiences after being spoiled by all the nice c/c++ magic the compiler helps you with: If you hook a function, and you know the exact prototype of that function ( including calling convention ), you can just give your hook-function the exact same prototype and write 100% c/c++ in the function body ( thus, getting rid of `__declspec(naked)` )

Answer (score 0):

Every compiler has a protocol for calling functions using assembly language.  The protocol may be stated deep in their manuals.

A faster method to find the function protocols is to have the compiler generate an assembly language listing for your function.

The best method for writing inline assembly is to:

1. First write the function in C++ source code
2. Next print out the assembly listing of the function.
3. Review and understand how the compiler generated assembly works.
4. Lastly, modify the internal assembly to suite your needs.

My preference is to write the C++ code as efficient as I can (or to help the compiler use optimal assembly language).  I then review the assembly listing.  I only change the inline assembly to invoke processor special features (such as block move instructions).